# How to get supported locales via your app, not the system?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, locale

I'm trying to get the list of locales supported by the app, but I'm only getting one.

I'm using android:localeConfig in manifest to add supported languages to phone settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<locale-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <locale android:name="es"/>
   <locale android:name="en"/>
</locale-config>
```

adding in manifest:

```
<manifest
    ...
    <application
        ...
        android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and using later the next function to set a new language:

```
fun setLanguage(localeSelected: String){

        // Select language, the selected locale; en, es, etc...
        if(getPreferredLocaleList().any { it.language == localeSelected }){
            AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(localeSelected))
        }

    }

fun getCurrentLanguage() : String {
        return Locale.getDefault().language
    }
```

Now I'm doing a dialog to select between those locales, but I'm getting only one and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
private fun getPreferredLocaleList(): List<Locale> {
        val adjustedLocaleListCompat = LocaleListCompat.getAdjustedDefault()
        val preferredLocaleList = mutableListOf<Locale>()
        for (index in 0 until adjustedLocaleListCompat.size()) {
            adjustedLocaleListCompat.get(index)?.let { preferredLocaleList.add(it) }
        }
        return preferredLocaleList
    }


fun showLanguageSelectorDialog(view: View){

        // AlertDialog builder instance to build the alert dialog
        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(view.context)

        // set the custom icon to the alert dialog
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.image_logo)

        // title of the alert dialog
        alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.language_selector))

        // list of the items to be displayed to the user in the form of list so that user can select the item from
        val listItems: MutableList<String> = emptyList<String>().toMutableList()
        getPreferredLocaleList().forEach { locale -> listItems.add(locale.language) }

        **var arrayOfListItems = listItems.toTypedArray()
        var currentLocale = getCurrentLanguage()
        var indexCurrentLocale: Int = arrayOfListItems.indexOf(currentLocale)**

        // the function setSingleChoiceItems is the function which builds the alert dialog with the single item selection
        alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(arrayOfListItems, indexCurrentLocale) { dialog, which ->
            // update the selected item which is selected by the user so that it should be selected
            // when user opens the dialog next time and pass the instance to setSingleChoiceItems method
            indexCurrentLocale = which

            // when selected an item the dialog should be closed with the dismiss method
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        // set the negative button if the user is not interested to select or change already selected item
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel)) { dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int -> dialog?.dismiss() }

        // create and build the AlertDialog instance with the AlertDialog builder instance
        val customAlertDialog = alertDialog.create()

        // show the alert dialog when the button is clicked
        customAlertDialog.show()
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: I have a problem, my application does not support languages that are not in the android system.
When I test the APK everything is fine, but after releasing to play store I have a problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Same is happening for me.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this that doesn't involved parsing the XML manually?

Comment: Not me casolorz

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a built-in way to do this. I just parsed the `locales_config.xml` via `getResources().getXml(R.xml.locales_config)`.

```
private String[] getLocalesFromResources() {
    final List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.locales_config);
    try {
        while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagName = xpp.getName();
            if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if ("locale".equals(tagName) && xpp.getAttributeCount() > 0 && xpp.getAttributeName(0).equals("name")) {
                    items.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
                }
            }
            xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return items.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: omg, why Java... what if I use `generateLocaleConfig = true` and don't create this config myself? How can I access it?

Comment: Lol you are complaining about my answer and then you are expecting more info. Good luck

Comment: because I know that you don't know anyway cause you manually added the list :) I asked question about it anyway

Comment: In 2022 there was no automated way for that, that's why it's done manually.